# how to create a policy template that defines a fixed value type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, strategy-pattern

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++03 application where I supply a policy `FooTraits` to a class `Foo`.

```
struct FooTraits
{
    enum { FooVal = 1 };
};

template< typename traits >
class Foo
{
public:
    typedef typename traits::FooVal foo_val; // errors on this line

    void FooDo( UINT matrix[ foo_val ] ) { /*...*/ };
};

typedef Foo< FooTraits > Foot;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    Foot f;
    UINT matrix[ Foot::foo_val ] = { /*...*/ };
    f.FooDo( matrix );
    return 0;
}
```

But, I get a whole series of compiler errors all on the `typedef`:

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'foo_val'
error C2838: 'FooVal' : illegal qualified name in member declaration
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

What's the correct way to create a policy that defines a fixed value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enumberated values introduced by `enum` are not, themselves, types.  But the `enum` itself is.  Therefore, in:

```
enum Dummy { FooVal = 1 };
```

`Dummy` is the type, not `FooVal`.  You can `typedef` `Dummy`, to wit:

```
struct FooTraits
{
    enum Dummy { FooVal = 1 };
};

/* ... */

template< typename traits >
class Foo
{
public:
    typedef typename traits::Dummy dummy;
  };
```

But you can't `typedef` `FooVal`, because it's not a type.  Trying to `typedef` `FooVal` would be like trying to do this:

```
int foo = 42;
typedef FooBar foo;
```

...which, of course, makes no sense.

Here's your code, fixed:

```
struct FooTraits
{
    enum { FooVal = 1 };
};

template< typename traits >
class Foo
{
public:
    void FooDo( unsigned matrix[ traits::FooVal] ) { matrix;/*...*/ };
};

typedef Foo< FooTraits > Foot;

int main(  )
{
    Foot f;
    unsigned matrix[ FooTraits::FooVal ] = { /*...*/ };
    f.FooDo( matrix );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`FooTraits::FooVal` is not a type. It's one possible value of the enum. You can't typedef something that isn't a type. You need either `decltype(FooTraits::FooVal)`, or to give a name to the enum.

Answer (score 0):

You can't typedef `traits::FooVal` because it is not type.

Use this syntax:

```
static const int foo_val = traits::FooVal;
```